# How to detect if i3-wm is being run or GNOME is being run in bash

Tags: linux, bash, window-managers, i3

I've been using i3-wm for about six months now, and I had to switch to GNOME because Discord was crashing a lot in i3. I had previously used the i3-msg command in my bashrc to make sure the borders of the terminal wouldn't be visible, as to use the entire screen space for the terminal. The specific command I run is:

```
    i3-msg -q border toggle
```

The problem is, when I use GNOME and I open up a terminal, the i3-msg command runs, and causes an error message evidently caused by the fact that i3 isn't running. The ideal scenario would be to add an if statement that checks if i3 is running, and if it is, then run the i3-msg command.

---

**My question: What is the most convenient way to determine which window manager / Desktop Environment is currently running in my system?**

---

Answer (score 0):

When i3 is active, there should be a proces called "i3". You could check that with pgrep.

```
if pgrep -x "i3" > /dev/null
then
  echo "i3 is running"
fi
```

`-x` is short for `--exact` – without it the if clause would still work, as long as no non-i3 process' name contains i3.

Omitting `> /dev/null` would print out the pid(s) found by pgrep.

Instead of `pgrep` you could also use `pidof` or `ps -C`. Instead of idiomatic if-then-fi you could also just use `&&` like `pidof i3 > /dev/null && echo "i3 is running" ||  echo "i3 is not running"`

Comment: what do you mean by "more concise"?

Comment: why would you have "less code"? I understand you use it in your bashrc?

Comment: if you put `ps -C i3 > /dev/null && ` before `i3-msg -q border toggle`-line in your bashrc, it will only trigger `i3-msg`, if i3-process is running… …so as you only have to type that once, why should it be "less code"?